# Generate Swagger docs from JSON?

Tags: rest, swagger

Swagger is all good when you design APIs first and implement then.

In my case I have existing legacy REST APIs that needs to be documented, and the only thing that I have is the actual JSON request/response objects.

Is there any way to feed JSON into Swagger to produce Swagger definition that could be used as the starting point for documentation?